# Upgrading postgresql v9.4 to v12 but get pg_upgrade: command not found

Tags: postgresql

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and currently running my app on postgresql 9.4.

I installed postgres version 12 and I'm trying to migrate my data over from postgres v9.4 to postgres v12. I also have postgres version 11 installed from an earlier time.

I'm trying to do this from `pg_upgrade`

So when I run `pg_lsclusters` I get:

```
9.4 main    5432 online                postgres  /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
11  main    5433 down                  postgres  /var/lib/postgresql/11/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
12  main    5434 down                  postgres  /var/lib/postgresql/12/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

When change to the postgres user (from the root) and run `pg_upgrade --check` I get:

```
pg_upgrade: command not found
```

Where is it looking for the `pg_upgrade` file/command?

Comment: I am tempted to say that if you want to upgrade a database, you should have at least a passing familiarity with the operating system you are using. On Linux, you have the choice of using absolute paths or using the environment variable `PATH`. You might consider using the script `pg_upgradecluster`.

Answer (score -1):

More than likely you need to install it.  For instance, on my openbsd servers when doing the upgrade, I need to install it as a separate package.  Beware that this actually ends up installing the previous version's binaries as well since the system needs to have both binaries to read the 'from' and write the 'to' data.  The command to load the pg_upgrade command is this:

```
pkg_add postgresql-pg_upgrade
```

As a part of that package, it will load the previous version's binary as a prerequisite.  You can see that list of binaries by getting the pkg info:

```
pkg_info -L postgresql-previous
```

As soon as that package is added you will have pg_upgrade available to you.